# How to get a Dockerfile mimic a docker hub image?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have the following section in my docker compose file:

```
...
 webserver:
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - web-root:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - certbot-etc:/etc/letsencrypt
      - certbot-var:/var/lib/letsencrypt
      - dhparam:/etc/ssl/certs
    depends_on:
      - nodejs
    networks:
      - app-network
...
```

Now I would like to have the ability to customize the nginx image a little by adding a few files to it, so I decided to change the compose file, and create a Dockerfile:

```
...
 webserver:
    
    build: 
      context: ./nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: webserver
...
```

Dockerfile in the ./nginx folder:

```
FROM nginx:latest
#COPY myscript.sh ./
```

At this point I haven't actually added the copy statement, but just wanted to try if this worked, however despite the container starting, by restarting the container it does not serve my website.

How do I get my Dockerfile to work the same way as my docker compose image statement?

[Source of my original docker compose.](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-a-containerized-node-js-application-with-nginx-let-s-encrypt-and-docker-compose)

I tried using a one liner Dockerfile

```
FROM nginx:latest
```

I also tried adding COPY statements so that my Dockerfile looked like this:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
```

I also tried adding all the optional VOLUME statements as they appear in the docker compose file:

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
VOLUME /etc/letsencrypt
VOLUME /var/lib/letsencrypt
VOLUME /etc/ssl/certs
```

As far as I have read these statements are optional as the compose file is sufficient, however I just tried even with specifying the Expose statements, but none of these did the trick.

Comment: What's the output of `docker image inspect <image-name>`?

Comment: It should work. Try doing `docker-compose build` to make sure that your image is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

As [Hans Kilian](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74741705/how-to-get-a-dockerfile-mimic-a-docker-hub-image#comment131912641_74741705) commented, after making/changing the Dockerfile and the docker compose file, one must rebuild the container by running:

```
docker compose build
```

That was all, the container now appears to work and act the same way using the Dockerfile as with the image reference in the compose file.